# Sending Zurb foundation emails (inky) with server

Tags: email, zurb-foundation, inky

I need to make custom e-mails where the server parses the inky e-mail and assigns the variables. For example: `hi {{user.name}}`.

Problem is if you use handlebars notation for the variables, the panini package of zurb foundation emails project will strip these. so the html output can't be parsed properly again by the server.

I just wan't to hear from you guys how you use the inky templating with custom variables.

Comment: Either use the data settings, write your own helper or use the `raw` helper.